# How to auto-complete filenames in texstudio

Tags: graphics, texstudio, external-files, auto-completion

I have lots of images to be used in a specific folder `./figures/`, so I set `\graphicspath{{./figures/}}`. However, how can I auto-complete filenames of these images in `\includegraphics{}`?

Comment: TeXstudio doesn't have this utility.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you. Is there a more convenient way to insert images rather than writing down the whole name?

Comment: Perhaps you can ask the maintainers of TeXstudio directly, in https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues.

Comment: Thank you for help.